# Merging references to objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, reference

I have an array of Cluster objects. Clusters have only 1 value - their ID.

```
Obj ID: 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
---------------------------
Index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

In this instance, each object with the same ID is the same object in memory. Now, I need to merge two of the objects such that all indices referencing those objects will have the same ID. I am currently doing this by simply setting the ID of one object to the ID of the other.

```
private static void merge( final Cluster[] clusters, final int left, final int right ) {
    cluster[right].id = cluster[left].id;
}
```

Which has this effect:

```
merge(1, 5);

Obj ID: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
---------------------------
Index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

However, there are still 3 objects. I haven't actually merged those references, only changed the object's ID. So I get this:

```
merge(4, 7);

Obj ID: 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
---------------------------
Index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Where the expected output is this:

```
Obj ID: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
---------------------------
Index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Constraints:

1. No imports (i.e. no Lists or Sets or Maps)
2. merge() must run in constant time

It does not need to be represented like this. I just need some way to say that clusters[a] and clusters[b] do or do not belong to the same cluster, and be able to merge two clusters.

Comment: `cluster[right].id = cluster[left].id;` -> `clusters[left].id = clusters[right].id;`?

Comment: That would work for the given example. However, the given example is extremely simplified compared to the actual input. The same issue would arise if the two merges were performed in the opposite order.

Comment: Questions that contain code that can't be compiled or that doesn't go as described are confusing.